# Extending SerializedObject with generic get method

Tags: c#, templates, generics, unity-game-engine

I would like to write an generic extension method for `SerializedObject` that could be used instead of `FindProperty` and then accessing `whateverValue` member, so I would be able to write `so.Get<Bool>("myValue")` instead of `so.FindProperty("myValue").boolValue`.

Here is how I would like to solve this if template specialization was a thing in C#:

```
public static T Get<T>(this SerializedObject so, string name) {
    Debug.LogError("Get called with unsuported type!");
}

public static bool Get<bool>(this SerializedObject so, string name) {
    return so.FindProperty(name).boolValue;
}
```

How can something like this be achieved in proper C#? I have also tried to add a `System.Type` parameter instead of specialization, but then what should the return type of such function be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a little bit of functional programming. One of the input parameters of the generic function *would be another function* that would define how the read the property:

```
    public static T Get<T>(this SerializedObject so, string name, Func<SerializedProperty, T> getter) {
        var property = so.FindProperty(name);
        if (property == null) {
            ;//handle "not found"
        }
        return getter(property);
    }
```

A couple of examples of how I would use it:

```
    internal bool ExampleBoolValue(SerializedObject so) {
        return so.Get("myBoolValue", (p => p.boolValue));
    }

    internal int ExampleIntValue(SerializedObject so) {
        return so.Get("myIntValue", (p => p.intValue));
    }
```

I don't have Unity installed on this machine so I'm not sure that Unity supports these .NET features.

**UPDATE** for setter method:

```
    public static void Set(this SerializedObject so, string name, Action<SerializedProperty> setter) {
        var property = so.FindProperty(name);
        if (property == null) {
            ;//handle "not found"
        }
        setter(property);
    }
```

Examples for setting a value:

```
    internal void SetExampleBoolValue(SerializedObject so, bool newValue) {
        so.Set("myBoolValue", (p => p.boolValue = newValue));
    }

    internal void SetExampleIntValue(SerializedObject so, int newValue) {
        so.Set("myIntValue", (p => p.intValue = newValue));
    }
```

[Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) takes 0..n parameters and does not return anything. [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) takes 0..n parameters and has to return something.

Comment: Well the whole point of this extension method was to write less, which your solution doesn't achieve.

Comment: It has the advantage of having central place where you can handle your errors and place your breakpoints. If that is not important in the project then a simple wrapper is enough, like in the answer of @Maxim Zabolotskikh.

Comment: Since I'm expanding the function to be able to use it as a setter as well, this solution could work better.

Comment: Could you please modify your answer so that it can also modify the `SerializedProperty`? Since Unity can't return references, my simple solution would be to pass `T? val = null` as last parameter.

Comment: @MarošBeťko I've updated the examples. For the setter I didn't use generics.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the magic of generic static to accomplish this.

The first class `GetPropertyValue<T>` will store your handler based on the type.  The static handler initially be set to your "unsupported" message, but the static constructor will call the InitGetPropertyValue class to initialize all the handlers.  Because this is within the static constructor of that class, it will only be called once, the first time the class is initialized.

Because the static variable of `GetPropertyValue<int>.Get` is different than the static variable `GetPropertyValue<string>.Get`, the handler for your type that you stored previously will be used each subsequent call.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    private static class GetPropertyValue<T>
    {
        static GetPropertyValue()
        {
            InitGetPropertyValue.Initialize();
        }

        public static Func<SerializedObject, string, T> Get = (so, name) =>
         {
             Debug.Print("Get called with unsupported type!");
             return default(T);
         };
    }

    private static class InitGetPropertyValue
    {
        static InitGetPropertyValue()
        {
            Debug.Print("Initializing property getters");
            GetPropertyValue<int>.Get = (so, name) => (int)so.FindProperty(name) ;
            GetPropertyValue<Guid>.Get = (so, name) => (Guid)so.FindProperty(name);
            GetPropertyValue<string>.Get = (so, name) => so.FindProperty(name).ToString();
        }

        public static bool Initialize()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this SerializedObject so, string name)
    {
        return GetPropertyValue<T>.Get(so, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the meaning of `=>` but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Seems like Unity works with C# 4 so I can't use this solution.

Comment: Look into lambda functions to gain more understanding of the `=>`.  I made one change that might help you, but what error do you get when you try to use this code?

Comment: I know what lambdas are, I'm just not familiar with the syntax on line 5. And the error I'm getting is `Feature 'expression body constructor and destructor' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 7 or greater. [Assembly-CSharp]` on 5th line of your example

Comment: That is a shorthand for creating methods that is available in C# 7 and beyond.   I changed it to use the traditional syntax so you can try it again.

Comment: Could you change it so the `Get` method would be `Val` method instead, that takes one optional parameter, which if is not null, will set the value?

Comment: And one more question. Why is there the Initialize function since it's doing nothing? Is the `InitGetPropertyValue` class lazy initialized or something similar?

Comment: Something needs to access the class in order to cause the static constructor to run.  Calling Initialize accesses the class causing the static constructor to execute.  Calling it again does nothing because the static constructor doesn't run again after the first call.

Answer (score 1):

While not a pretty solution, a working one would be sth like:

```
public static T Get<T>(this SerializedObject so, string name) {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool){
        return (T)(object)so.FindProperty(name).boolValue;
    }
    else if {
    ...
    }
    else {
        Debug.LogError("Get called with unsuported type!");
    }
}
```

I'd personally go with sth like:

```
public static bool GetBoolean(this SerializedObject so, string name)
public static int GetInt(this SerializedObject so, string name)
```

The semantics stays the same, but implementation is cleaner.

Comment: I am used to coding in C++ and there such things can be written really nicely with the use of templates. But since this is C#, those `GetBoolean` and `GetInt` functions should work nicely :D